# How do I make an Excel chart x-axis dynamic based on checkbox selection

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a chart on Sheet1, showing prices of an apple across different markets, drawing data from Sheet2. List of countries are on the x-axis. Price points are on the y-axis.

Sheet1 also has a list of checkboxes (Sheet 1: S18:S34) for user to select which markets they would like to view. These checkboxes are linked to Sheet2: K29:K45.

To make this work, I am trying to get Sheet2 to hide the rows of the non-selected markets, so that the chart only shows data of the selected markets.

My attempt:

**Sheet1:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'To activate MarketsSelection macro once checkboxes are changed

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S18:S34")) Is Nothing Then

    Call MarketsSelection
    
End If
    
End Sub
```

**To update Sheet2:**

```
Sub MarketsSelection()

' To unhide all rows first

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Rows("29:45").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False

' To hide markets not chosen

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    For Each c In Range("K29:K45")
     If c.Value = "" Then Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
    Next
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    
End Sub
```

However, the above are not working for me. Any advice on change of code/method is highly appreciated!

[Concept of Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIiuC.png)

[Concept of Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4slSR.png)

Comment: I don't think changing checkboxes causes the `Worksheet_Change` event to fire.

Comment: Assign the same macro to all of the checkboxes to achieve the effect you're looking for. @BigBen is correct that the `Worksheet_Change` event does not fire when the checkbox is clicked, regardless that it is linked to a cell.

Comment: Thanks all! I have managed to solve this by assigning the same macro to all checkboxes.

Comment: Changing the checkboxes in sheet 1 changes values in the linked cells in sheet 2. What will fire is the `Worksheet_Change` procedure for sheet 2, not the one for sheet 1. So move the code to sheet 2's code module.